# I can not create buttons for possible answers android studio

Tags: android

I have an issue with a small project in android studio where on animal drawings guess things etc. But guess I have to write the name to accept a button and image lights up and goes to the next , what I want you to show me an answer with buttons say 3 button 1 is the correct answer and the other two false I took a long time with this and even I can not do it if I would appreciate any help

Here the code of the class where the shadows and images run

```js
public class Categoria extends Activity {

    public static String[] nombre_cosa={"cerdo","ave","caballo","conejo","elefante","gallina","gato",
            "rana","perro","pato","oveja","leon","jirafa",
            "raton","vaca","autobus","automovil","avion","bicicleta","camioneta",
            "casa","celular","guitarra","motocicleta","silla","television","durazno","fresa","mango",
            "uvas","sandia","platano","coco","pera","naranja","manzana",
            "bart","batman","cerebro","chavo","goku","homero","marge",
            "patricio","pepa","phineas","quico","spiderman","thor","superman"};

    public static String[] sombra_cosa={"s_cerdo","s_ave","s_caballo","s_conejo","s_elefante","s_gallina","s_gato",
            "s_rana","s_perro","s_pato","s_oveja","s_leon","s_jirafa",
            "s_raton","s_vaca","s_autobus","s_automovil","s_avion","s_bicicleta","s_camioneta",
            "s_casa","s_celular","s_guitarra","s_motocicleta","s_silla","s_television","s_durazno","s_fresa","s_mango",
            "s_uvas","s_sandia","s_platano","s_coco","s_pera","s_naranja","s_manzana",
            "s_bart","s_batman","s_cerebro","s_chavo","s_goku","s_homero","s_marge",
            "s_patricio","s_pepa","s_phineas","s_quico","s_spiderman","s_thor","s_superman"};

    public static boolean[] estado={false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false};

    public static int cosas_adivinadas=0;
    private int intentos=3;
    private Button aceptar;
    private TextView mensaje_intentos,mensaje_cuenta;
    private EditText usuario_cosa;
    private int numero_generado=0;
    private ImageView miimagen;
    private MediaPlayer reproductor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria);
        aceptar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnaceptar);
        mensaje_intentos=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblintentos);
        mensaje_cuenta=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblcuenta);
        usuario_cosa=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtcosa);
        miimagen=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcosa);
        CargarPreferencias();
        new MiTarea().execute();
        reproductor= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yansha);
        reproductor.setLooping(true);
        reproductor.start();
        mensaje_intentos.setText("Tiene " + intentos + " intentos");
        aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String nombre=usuario_cosa.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                if(nombre.equals(nombre_cosa[numero_generado]))
                {
                    establecer_cosa(numero_generado);
                    estado[numero_generado]=true;
                    cosas_adivinadas++;
                    esperar();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    intentos=intentos-1;
                    mensaje_intentos.setText("Tiene " + intentos + " intentos");
                }

                if (intentos==0)
                {
                    removerPreferencias();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Categoria.this,Perder.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        reproductor.start();
    }

    public void esperar()
    {
        new CountDownTimer(5000,1000)
        {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mensaje_cuenta.setText("Generando en " + (millisUntilFinished/1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                if (cosas_adivinadas==nombre_cosa.length)
                {
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    new MiTarea().execute();
                    mensaje_cuenta.setText("");
                    usuario_cosa.setText("");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void CargarPreferencias()
    {
        SharedPreferences mispreferencias = getSharedPreferences("PreferenciaCosa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        intentos=mispreferencias.getInt("intentos",3);
        cosas_adivinadas=mispreferencias.getInt("adivinados",0);
        for (int i=0;i<nombre_cosa.length;i++)
        {
            estado[i]=mispreferencias.getBoolean(nombre_cosa[i],false);
        }
    }

    public void GuardarPreferencias()
    {
        SharedPreferences mispreferencias = getSharedPreferences("PreferenciaCosa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mispreferencias.edit();
        editor.putInt("intentos",intentos);
        editor.putInt("adivinados",cosas_adivinadas);
        for (int i=0;i<nombre_cosa.length;i++)
        {
            editor.putBoolean(nombre_cosa[i], estado[i]);
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void establecer_cosa(int numero)
    {
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(nombre_cosa[numero], "drawable", getPackageName());
        miimagen.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    private void establecer_sombra(int numero)
    {
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(sombra_cosa[numero], "drawable", getPackageName());
        miimagen.setImageResource(resId);
    }


    private void removerPreferencias()
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PreferenciaCosa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (intentos==0)
        {
            removerPreferencias();
        }
        else
        {
            GuardarPreferencias();
        }
        reproductor.pause();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (reproductor.isPlaying())
        {
            reproductor.stop();
            reproductor.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class MiTarea extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private int valor_generado;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            do {
                valor_generado=((int)(Math.random()*nombre_cosa.length));
            }while(estado[valor_generado]);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            numero_generado = valor_generado;
            establecer_sombra(valor_generado);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: i don't get it. Punctuation will helpful at first. Show what you have done and we can talk about it. We don't do you homework dude.

Comment: You want to have couple of different activities or fragments with 3 buttons and to check for right answers depending on a image?
Am I right?

Comment: The application generates random shadows and a EditText write the correct answer then click on a button to accept the shadow lights and go to the next image. Want it to appear in response options buttons ie 3 wrong and that is correct

Comment: thanks for answering

Comment: you should at least create that 3 buttons and then try what you can to implement the function that you want (generate random number, set the text, compare to answer after click) and then update your code in this post

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable like this:

```
boolean isTextCorrect = false;
```

In default, the button is invisible.
Implement a listener. If the text in the textfield changed and its correct switch isTextCorrect to true and make the button visible (clickable).

```
if(isTextCorrect){
    button.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: sorry you did not understand very well please be more specific greetings thank you for comment