# add text to buttons randomly android studio

Tags: android

as I can add those buttons at random name to start a different name on a button

```js
public static String[] warriors={"tan","android16","andsaroid17","goku","bardock","bills","boo"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can random a number from 0 to the length of the array of String and then set the text to the button.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int random_number = rand.nextInt(warriors.length);

button.setText(warriors[random_number]);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I thank you very much run one last question sorry to bother you as I do to make these buttons serve as a response to guess a correct image a two buttons but with incorrect answer

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question, can you rephrase it? and put your code in your question above

Comment: guess something like the image of some animal, thing etc. image and possible answers shown on the buttons I have it but I write the answer EDITTEXT what I would like it to appear on the buttons the correct answer and two false

Comment: so you want to compare the text of the button to the answer text, if they're the same then it's correct? if that so, just add 'onClickListener` and then compare the Strings with this logic `((Button)view).getText().toString().compare(answer)`
please edit your main question and give some illustration of what you want to achieve

Comment: works like a shadow of the image appears , type the correct response to press a button if correct shade lights up and goes to another shade. want it to run so were three buttons with each correct answer the other two buttons wrong answers.
is something like the shadow guess the app in advance thank you very much

Comment: please create a new question for this, that would be out of topic if I answer it here :)
and please mark this as the answer, thanks

Comment: I apologize question here is the link if you could help me please thank you!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654188/i-can-not-create-buttons-for-possible-answers-android-studio/32654386#32654386

Comment: please help with this take many days and still can not with what it says on the question to let